# Disable connection string pooling in .net application

Tags: .net, sql-server

I want to disable pooling in my connection string:
I tried it with `Pooling=false` and with an `Application Name="Guidish"`.
Here the important part of the connection string:

```
Pooling=False;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
Application Name=".Net SqlClient Data Provider67ad035e-c4b4-4382-bdce-e1928cafe5bb"
```

but no luck. The application still uses a connection from the pool and does not create a new one.

Any ideas?

I want to test a DB connection and therefore I want to create a new connection every time and not take a connection of the pool.

Comment: @Bhushan: Your edit was too substantial. OP has provided his connection-string which might be correct or not. But you have changed it to a list of attributes which is not a connection-string anymore.

Comment: @TimSchmelter :Click on edited and see..he has the same connection string. I had just put each attribute on separate line to make it more readable.

Comment: `The connection string is actually a list of keyword/attribute pairs. The keyword is not case-sensitive whereas the value may be.` It's just a guess but try it lower case.